# sql server 2012 t-sql change value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2012

In a t-sql 2012 stored procedure, I would like  to know if my solution to solve the problem is correct and/or if you have any other suggestion(s) on how I can complete the task I am listing below:

In an existing SQL Server 2012 stored procedure, there is a table called `Atrn` that is truncated every night. The table `Atrn` has a column called `ABS` that is populated with incorrect data.

The goal is to place the correct value into the `ABS` column that is located in when the stored procedure is executing.

**Note**: The goal is to fix the problem now since it is a production problem. The entire stored procedure that updates the `dbo.Atrn` table will be rewritten in the near future.

My plan is to:

1. create a temp table called `#Atrnwork` that will contain the columns 
   `Atrnworkid int` and `ABSvalue double` .
2. The value in the column called `Atrnworkid` in the `#Atrnwork` table will obtain its value from the key of the `Atrn` table, called `atrnid` by doing a select into. At the same time, the value for `ABSvalue` will be obtained by running some sql when the select into occurs
3. The main table called `Atrn` will be changed with a update statement that looks something like:

   ```
   Update Atrn
   set ABS = ABSvalue
   join Atrn.atrnid = #Atrnwork.Atrnworkid
   ```

In all can you tell me what a good solution is to solve this problem and/or display some sql on how to solve the problem listed above?

Comment: if the table is truncated every night why do you need to worry about the incorrect value in one of its columns?

Comment: Are you fixing only the bad data here? have you checked what is causing the incorrect data? :-)

Comment: The data is incorrect since the original query is wrong that is in production